# Google Chrome Extension: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

After updating my chrome to version 37.0.2062.102 m, my extension can't send cross origin request.
The error message is: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here I give the source code to reproduce the problem:

**manifest.json:**

```
    {
    "name": "tes2",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": ".",
    "devtools_page": "main.html",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
    "content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'  chrome-extension-resource: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval';  connect-src *; frame-src *;"
}
```

**main.html:**

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="js/addPanel.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**js/addPanel.js:**

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create(
    'Session Management',
    null, // No icon path
    'Panel/sessionmanagement.html',
    null);
```

**panel/sessionmanagement.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="../lib/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="start-button">Start</button>
</body>
  <script src="../js/tes.js"></script>    
</html>
```

**js/tes.js:**

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $('#start-button').click(loginCallback);

});

var loginCallback = function () { 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://google.com",
        success: function(html, status, xhr){
            alert(html);
        }
    });
}
```

**lib/jquery-2.1.1.js:**
*please download by yourself.*

Comment: What happens if you explicitly set the schema? `url: "http://localhost/drupal"`

Comment: This should have been broken on your old version of Chrome too.  Are you sure it just now broke and you didn't change any code?  Are you sure you're actually including the CORS headers as-needed for your application?

Comment: @Xan
It's still not working even after I change the schema to 
url: "http://localhost/drupal"

Comment: @Brad
Yes, I didn't change the code.

Comment: @user3738126 So then the CORS headers aren't there anymore.

Comment: @Brad
Is there something I can do to add the CORS headers?

Comment: @user3738126 Cannot reproduce your problem. Have you reloaded the extension after updating the permissions list?

Comment: @RobW
Yes, I've also installed it on another computer.

Comment: What do you see at `chrome://net-internals/#events`? Any redirect to a different host? You should edit your question to include the necessary details to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user3738126 Yes... add the appropriate CORS headers to the response for the resource you are requesting.  I can't tell you any more than that because you haven't shown any of your server-side code, or even what the response headers are now.

Comment: @user3738126 What jquery version are you using?

Comment: @Brad this question is about Chrome extensions. There shouldn't be any need for CORS headers if the appropriate permissions are set in the manifest.

Comment: @rsanchez Ah, that makes sense.  I missed that key part of info when I read the question.

Comment: @RobW
I've edited the question, so I hope you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @rsanchez
I use jquery-2.1.1

Comment: @user3738126 See the linked duplicate. I've requested clarification for this "bug" at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409685, FYI.